The SSL connection error between two app running on docker
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and ASP.NET MVC web app app running on docker.
When the web app tries to send request to the Web API, I get the following exception:

Exception: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan1 buffer) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Here is my docker-compose file:
version: '3.4'

networks:
  la-network:
    driver: bridge 

services:
  la-web:
    image: la-web:latest
    depends_on:
      - "la-database"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: LA.WebPortal/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - la-network
      
  la-api:
    image: la-api:latest
    depends_on:
      - "la-database"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: LA.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always      
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__LADb: "host=la-database;port=5432;database=db;username=user;password=pass"
    networks:
      - la-network 
  
  la-database:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pass"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
    networks:
      - la-network
volumes:
  db_volume:

In both the Web API and web app, I use following configuration for HttpClient:
_ = services.AddHttpClient("lahttp")
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
});

and
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("lahttp");

Can you please help me?

What are you trying to access from where and how?

The default for containerized ASP.NET apps is to only listen for HTTP on port 8080. Why do you expect it to listen for HTTPS?

Firstly, please make sure the SSL is necessary or not, the connection between the docker and docker for internal use is no need for https.
